# How to get AWS EC2 costs for storage only (EBS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, storage

I get into AWS Cost Explorer, then into service EC2, and immediately see the cost per day of EC2 instances, and that is great.

However I need to monitor storage costs (EBS) separately, to compare allocation strategies with respect to cost, and can't find a way.

Best regards

Answer (score 2):

In the filter list on the right hand side, you can filter on "Usage Type Group".  There are seven usage type groups for EBS: you can check all of them and see only costs related to EBS.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it.